# Is it possible to return if it is a specific error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, discord.js

I was creating my bot discord when I got a missing permissions error, I was wondering if it was possible to not display the error if it's only a permissions error.

Let me explain, the error starts with `DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message` and I thought that `if (err.includes("DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message") return` might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/message) Has a specific structure. You're interested in the `.message`.

```
if (err.message.includes("DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message") return;
```

Comment: Tysm !! I didn't know it !